# Using extra CSS file with Mkdocs hosted by ReadTheDocs

Tags: read-the-docs, mkdocs

I have written some custom CSS I would like to be included in a Mkdocs site hosted by ReadTheDocs. It is not working because RTD isn't serving the CSS file.

I have a `.readthedocs.yml` file that asks RTD to use Mkdocs:

```
version: 2
mkdocs:
  configuration: .mkdocs.yml
```

My `.mkdocs.yml` file references the fact that I'm using a custom CSS file:

```
docs_dir: my-docs-directory
theme:
  name: 'material'
extra_css:
  - '.mkdocs.material.css'
```

ReadTheDocs reports that the docs built fine, but when I load them the custom CSS isn't in effect. If I open the browser Console I see this error:

> Refused to apply style from 'https://private-site.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/.mkdocs.material.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

If I open the CSS file URL in its own tab I see a "404 - Not found" page.

I tried including the CSS file in both root (where `.readthedocs.yml` and `.mkdocs.yml` live) and in my docs directory (`my-docs-directory`), but neither work.

I think I need RTD to somehow know to serve the CSS file up as a static file, but all guidelines I could find about this are specific to Sphinx.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue is due to the dot at the beginning of `.mkdocs.material.css`. It looks like MkDocs (`mkdocs build`, I used MkDocs v1.0) won't copy hidden files -- the dot at the beginning denotes a hidden file on Unix systems -- to the output directory. I think if you rename the file to be `mkdocs.material.css` without the leading dot and update the reference in your `mkdocs.yml`, it should work.

The more cryptic error message you see on Read the Docs (`Refused to apply style ...`) is because the link tag (`<link>`) to the CSS file is still generated in the build output but MkDocs didn't actually copy the CSS file because it was hidden. As a result it gives a 404. Read the Docs sends a header telling browsers to do strict MIME checking which is an important security measure when handling user uploaded files. Because there's a link to a CSS file but the response is a 404 with HTML, the browser rejects the style.

Comment: Ah, I missed the dot. Good catch. Now that I see it, I am certain that this is the issue. The 404 error page is HTML, not CSS, which is causing the error message.